Imprimir JSON bien formateado en C#
Tengo este string como Json que recibo al hacer una petición a un servicio.
Así está visualizado como texto plano
"{\r\n \"OperationType\": \"SAVE_LINK\",\r\n \"Documents\": [\r\n {\r\n \"DocId\": \"****\",\r\n \"DocVersion\": \"20230429\",\r\n \"Title\": \"Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal\",\r\n \"LinkToInforceVersion\": \"https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW6EIBCGn6bc2oDaXT1wsW3STTZNs2sfYESiJMhYQKt9-g56KclHJsM35J_vWfut0WuUyiiLI0b0LGwO3TbKxs-aRWiDFJw_nJUgMmKvz3TlREE8Eyci9UqiSsJupRGRZkRyRZJFskXSRclAxRnsKyopUm0W3UArOUPfaV9vVEWMYG-aMpxYGPDnAxbTQzToavBHRNN18vrG0xFlXlRs0T6QIDOe5bzIKjaYfrgS8RgIGrwaPqHX8uKMMvgEYVqZCV_OpFmw9934b9dzjPRlG93xxmCa7HZDS9F2bcJAe8yjdvHiXsDjHLSlBUZYqX83v7rBd8pg9xyPgmfFH91HPct-AQAAWKE\",\r\n \"LinkToVersion\": \"https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW7DIAyGn2bcNoU2a9MDl3STVqmapjbb3SFWgkRwBiRL9vQzyWVIH7LMZ_j5HtEvFc5RaaMt9RTJi7A4ckuvKj-iiFAHJbPs4agls2PW-sjbnsmZZ-bApF7BnJKwWmlEphmZXJlkmWyZdFkI0HEE-0JayVSbCSuoVSbIN-jLhatIEewNOcNBhI5-3mEyLURDrgS_RTRNo66vWVqy2OcnMaEPLKgv06KLKDrTdlcmbn5A8Lr7gBbVxRlt6AnCMAsTPp1Jo2Dvq_HfLscY-cY6uu1MwDDY5UaWk63aQIG_Mfb84MWdwdMY0HL-Hmbu380vVvTGGeya41Fmu_wP_9FJj30BAAA=WKE\",\r\n \"FireUrl\": null\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n}"

Y así como JSON:
{
  "OperationType": "SAVE_LINK",
  "Documents": [
    {
      "DocId": "********",
      "DocVersion": "20230429",
      "Title": "Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal",
      "LinkToInforceVersion": "https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW6EIBCGn6bc2oDaXT1wsW3STTZNs2sfYESiJMhYQKt9-g56KclHJsM35J_vWfut0WuUyiiLI0b0LGwO3TbKxs-aRWiDFJw_nJUgMmKvz3TlREE8Eyci9UqiSsJupRGRZkRyRZJFskXSRclAxRnsKyopUm0W3UArOUPfaV9vVEWMYG-aMpxYGPDnAxbTQzToavBHRNN18vrG0xFlXlRs0T6QIDOe5bzIKjaYfrgS8RgIGrwaPqHX8uKMMvgEYVqZCV_OpFmw9934b9dzjPRlG93xxmCa7HZDS9F2bcJAe8yjdvHiXsDjHLSlBUZYqX83v7rBd8pg9xyPgmfFH91HPct-AQAAWKE",
      "LinkToVersion": "https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW7DIAyGn2bcNoU2a9MDl3STVqmapjbb3SFWgkRwBiRL9vQzyWVIH7LMZ_j5HtEvFc5RaaMt9RTJi7A4ckuvKj-iiFAHJbPs4agls2PW-sjbnsmZZ-bApF7BnJKwWmlEphmZXJlkmWyZdFkI0HEE-0JayVSbCSuoVSbIN-jLhatIEewNOcNBhI5-3mEyLURDrgS_RTRNo66vWVqy2OcnMaEPLKgv06KLKDrTdlcmbn5A8Lr7gBbVxRlt6AnCMAsTPp1Jo2Dvq_HfLscY-cY6uu1MwDDY5UaWk63aQIG_Mfb84MWdwdMY0HL-Hmbu380vVvTGGeya41Fmu_wP_9FJj30BAAA=WKE",
      "FireUrl": null
    }
  ]
}

Estoy tratando de imprimirlo por pantalla en mi .aspx para que se vea bonito y bien formateado (como un JSON). Algo así:
{
  "OperationType": "SAVE_LINK",
  "Documents": [
    {
      "DocId": "********",
      "DocVersion": "20230429",
      "Title": "Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal",
      "LinkToInforceVersion": "https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW6EIBCGn6bc2oDaXT1wsW3STTZNs2sfYESiJMhYQKt9-g56KclHJsM35J_vWfut0WuUyiiLI0b0LGwO3TbKxs-aRWiDFJw_nJUgMmKvz3TlREE8Eyci9UqiSsJupRGRZkRyRZJFskXSRclAxRnsKyopUm0W3UArOUPfaV9vVEWMYG-aMpxYGPDnAxbTQzToavBHRNN18vrG0xFlXlRs0T6QIDOe5bzIKjaYfrgS8RgIGrwaPqHX8uKMMvgEYVqZCV_OpFmw9934b9dzjPRlG93xxmCa7HZDS9F2bcJAe8yjdvHiXsDjHLSlBUZYqX83v7rBd8pg9xyPgmfFH91HPct-AQAAWKE",
      "LinkToVersion": "https://localhost:44342/Content/Documento.aspx?params=H4sIAAAAAAAEAE2PwW7DIAyGn2bcNoU2a9MDl3STVqmapjbb3SFWgkRwBiRL9vQzyWVIH7LMZ_j5HtEvFc5RaaMt9RTJi7A4ckuvKj-iiFAHJbPs4agls2PW-sjbnsmZZ-bApF7BnJKwWmlEphmZXJlkmWyZdFkI0HEE-0JayVSbCSuoVSbIN-jLhatIEewNOcNBhI5-3mEyLURDrgS_RTRNo66vWVqy2OcnMaEPLKgv06KLKDrTdlcmbn5A8Lr7gBbVxRlt6AnCMAsTPp1Jo2Dvq_HfLscY-cY6uu1MwDDY5UaWk63aQIG_Mfb84MWdwdMY0HL-Hmbu380vVvTGGeya41Fmu_wP_9FJj30BAAA=WKE",
      "FireUrl": null
    }
  ]
}

En mi código tengo actualmente esto:
var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

if (buttonId == "WebPagePopupDownloadLinkButton")
{
    var jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    using (var stringReader = new StringReader(jsonResponse))
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(stringReader);
        var jsonWriter = new JsonTextWriter(stringWriter) { Formatting = Formatting.Indented };
        jsonWriter.WriteToken(jsonReader);
        JsonResultLiteral.Text =  stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}

Y en mi .aspx tengo este Literal para imprimir el texto:
<div>
   <asp:Literal ID="JsonResultLiteral" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"/>
</div>

Haciendo esto, se imprime por pantalla exactamente lo que tenía al principio, con \r y \n literalmente escritos en pantalla, no cambia nada:

El código lo he sacado de aquí. He probado también el resto de soluciones propuestas en el hilo pero ninguna me ha servido.
¿Qué está pasando en mi caso? ¿Acaso tiene que ver con el .aspx? Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.
P.D: Me gustaría utilizar la librería NewtonSoft.Json para solucionar el problema, pero me sirve cualquier otra.

Lo que no me queda claro es si los \r\n que mostrás, son esos caracteres literalmente o son realmente retornos de carro y avances de línea dentro de la cadena y los estás poniendo así solo para representarlos.

@jachguate Son retornos de carro y avances de línea, pero no se procesan como tal, sino que aparecen literalmente en el texto. He actualizado la pregunta para que se entienda mejor.

Publiqué una respuesta pero, por lo que comentas sobre que se ven literalmente los \r\n en la salida, me queda la duda de si no realmente tenemos "\\r\\n" cada vez que los vemos. En todo caso, si así fuera, puedes seguir aplicando lo que te dejé como primera opción, pero cambiaría la sustitución del texto. En el segundo caso, habría que sustituír "\\r\\n" por "\r\n" para que funcione.

De acuerdo a la documentación, el control Literal

Reserva una ubicación en la página web para mostrar texto estático.

Recordemos que lo que asignemos a la propiedad Text se va a desplegar en una página web, por lo que se espera que su contenido sea HTML:
Aquí, vas a enfrentar varios problemas y tienes básicamente dos maneras de resolverlos:
Sustituciones
Recuerda que HTML no tiene una representación para saltos de línea como parte del contenido y que elimina los espacios a la izquierda del contenido a desplegar, que considera parte de la indentación. Puedes verlo directamente con un ejemplo:


<p>una
    sola
          línea sin espacios a la izquierda ni intermedios
</p>



Para lograr un salto de línea en HTML, se utiliza la etiqueta <br> y para lograr espacios la entidad &nbsp;


<p>varias<br>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;líneas<br>
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;con espacios a la izquierda 
</p>



Puedes hacer sustituciones de texto sobre tu cadena para ir resolviendo estos problemas uno a uno, por ejemplo:
<asp:Literal ID="miLiteral" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"/>

string strTemp = "{\r\n  \"Esto\": \"Es una prueba\"\r\n}";
miLiteral.Text = strTemp.Replace("\r\n", "<br/>").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;");

Usar etiqueta pre
Otra opción es envolver el contenido en una etiqueta <pre> que mostrará el texto tal como está "escrito", con sus espacios y saltos de línea (es la etiqueta que usualmente se utiliza para publicar código fuente, por ejemplo).


<pre>
  líneas
    aparecen
  tal como
    están escritas
</pre>



Así, tomarías el contenido tal como está, pero antes de asignarlo, lo "envuelves" en el inicio y fín de la etiqueta, por ejemplo:
<asp:Literal ID="miLiteral" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough"/>

string strTemp = "{\r\n  \"Esto\": \"Es una prueba\"\r\n}";
miLiteral.Text = "<pre>\r\n" + strTemp + "\r\n</pre>";

OJO: Esto que sugiero en esta sección, no lo he probado y no tengo forma de probarlo ahora, pero pienso que debiera funcionar. Agradezco que me confirmes si lo pruebas y no lo hace.
Edición
El AP editó la pregunta mientras escribía la respuesta original, me llamó la atención que la imagen muestra que se imprimen literalmente los caracteres \r\n en la salida, lo que me hizo pensar que la cadena realmente traía incrustados esos caracteres literales y no los caracteres de control que representan.
Para aplicar la primera solución, entonces, habría que cambiar la sustitución por:
strTemp.Replace("\\r\\n", "<br/>").Replace(" ", "&nbsp;").Replace("\\\"", "\"");

Observa como ahora también he incluído una tercera sustitución para las comillas, que aparecen como \".
Para la segunda, habría que agregar una sustitución, en la línea de:
miLiteral.Text = "<pre>\r\n" + strTemp.Replace("\\r\\n", "\r\n").Replace("\\\"", "\"") + "\r\n</pre>";

